# Induction. Prove: $n! \ge 3^{n-1}/2$ for $n\geq1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Induction. Prove: $n! \ge 3^{n-1}/2$ for $n\geq1$

For $n = 1$, $1! \geq 1/2$ which is true.

When I start with induction I can't prove it for all natural numbers. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: "*When I start with induction I can't prove it for all natural numbers.*"  How about doing the first few base cases directly, and then beginning induction only after it becomes easy to do?  Note: $4! = 4\cdot 3! > 3\cdot 3!$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions are better received when they include some efforts from the author. You should edit your question to include what you get when you "start with induction".

Comment: Thank you Arnaud, first time here

Comment: Much easier here to treat $1$ as a special case and start your base case with $n=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that $$ n! \ge 3^{(n-1)}/2$$

The problem begs for Mathematical Induction proof.

The statement it true for $n=1$ and $n=2$

If the statement is true for $k\ge 2$ , then

$$(k+1)!= (k+1)k! \ge (k+1)( 3^{(k-1)}/2)\ge 3( 3^{(k-1)}/2) = 3^{k}/2$$

Thus the statement is true for all $n\ge 1.$

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the comment. I fixed my solution. Please check the edit.

Comment: Exercise.  Show for k > 0, r > 1, n! eventually greater than k$r^n$ and find the smallest n for which  k$r^n$ <= n!.

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:   for $\,n \ge 2\,$:

$$
\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n!} = n+1 \ge 3 = \dfrac{3^n}{3^{n-1}} \;\;\implies\;\;\dfrac{(n+1)!}{3^n} \ge \dfrac{n!}{3^{n-1}} \ge \dfrac{(n-1)!}{3^{n-2}} \ge \ldots \ge \dfrac{2!}{3^1} \gt \dfrac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Induction step:

Assume $k!\ge 3^{\frac {k-1}2}$. Can you prove:

$(k+1)! = k!(k+1) \ge 3^{\frac {k-1} 2}(k+1) \underbrace{\ge}_{\text{prove this}} 3^{\frac {k} 2}$?

Note: $3^{\frac k2} = 3^{\frac {k-1}{2}}3^{\frac 12}$.

So can you prove that if $k \ge 1$ that $k + 1 \ge \sqrt{3}$?

Can you prove if $k \ge 1$ then $(k+1)^2 \ge 3$?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement**: Prove using induction that $$n! \geq \dfrac{3^{n-1}}{2}; \forall n \geq 1$$

**Solution**

- Base case: For $n = 1$

$$1! = 1 \geq \dfrac{3^{1-1}}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \tag{1}$$
which is true.

- Assume that the given relation is true of any $n \geq 1$.
- The for $n + 1$, we have 
  \begin{align}
    (n + 1)! = (n + 1) \times n! \geq \dfrac{3^{n+1-1}}{2} = \dfrac{3^n}{2} = \dfrac{3 \times 3^{n- 1}}{2} = 3 \times \dfrac{3^{n-1}}{2}
  \end{align}
  The relation ($\geq$) above is true as using the relation, $n! \geq \dfrac{3^{n-1}}{2}$ and also using the base case, the minimum value possible for $n$ after the base case is $n = 2$, and $n + 1 = 2 + 1 \geq 3$. Hence this proves the claim.